# Stuck showing my information taken from the input field

Tags: html, jquery

Hello all i am stuck and was wondering if anyone could help me im new to developing with js i have this code i managed to throw together and suprissinally it works.. but the issue i am having is the data i have collected i need to display it in the span element.

HTML code - Takes the number from the input field Span element to display the math calculated..

```
<input type="text" value="" id="level" />
<span id='cash'></span>
```

My Code - the code gets users input and calculates it like ((2500 * input) * multiplier) the code itself works as it does in the alert but i am struggling to get the data and display it in the span box

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#level").keyup(function() {
    // get the users data
    let dInput = $(this).val();
    // Calculate cost based on input and hardcoded math
    let cost = ((2500 * dInput) * 1.00);
    // Show the cost in the span id?
    $('#cash').load(cost);
    alert(cost);
  });
});
```

Have got the code to work where it gets the users inputted data and calculates it by the sum.

All the code works but i can't seem to get it to show the collected data in a span or that..

Comment: What are your expectations?

Comment: 1) Why are you doing this in JQuery?  It can be handled with regular JS.  2) have you tried logging the value of `cost` to see if it's computing properly?

Comment: I am creating a script in my website which uses php so when the user visits the page he will see a input box asking him to put his level in and based on what level he enters the code does its calculations as it does but i can not get it to pass the data to the span element to show the user the data gathered which will be formatted 10 $2,500 in the span element.

Comment: Please do not edit your questions into a state that won't allow to understand the initial problem any more. Doing so invalidates answers and makes your question useless for future visitors.

Comment: Sorry i have fixed the problem above if i wish to post the fix do i answer my own question sorry i am new to using this for actually asking for help, I have used it for reference tons of times so you can say i'm a newbie when coming to things on here

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer, not by editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery the .load() method is used to get data from the server. Instead you want to use .text() to update the text content. Here is the code I would use. Please let me know if it works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#level").keyup(function() {
      // get the user's data
      let dInput = $(this).val();
      // Calculate cost based on input and hardcoded math
      let cost = ((2500 * dInput) * 1.00);
      // Show the cost in the span id
      $('#cash').text(cost);
  });
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for the info but sadly that did not work either it apears to broken the code, error below.

"<a class='gotoLine' href='#51:24'>51:24</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementById')"

Comment: @SmartWebProductions That error can't be coming from this code.